# Unable to visit other routes with ngrok

Tags: node.js, api, localhost, ngrok

I run ngrok with my localhost 3000 and everything works fine when I visit the root path “/“ but it fails when I try to visit any other path like “/page/doSomething”.

How do I visit other routes/paths? My base route is not where I really want to test.

My server is created with node.

Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: It would be helpful to see some code of your server. And also one more question: Does the correct page open when you visit localhost:3000/page/doSomething?

Comment: It’s an api, I don’t get any response when I visit “/page/doSomething” but it does when I visit “/“. I’ll post my code soon

Comment: Hehe okay, in that case: does the correct action trigger when you execute it on localhost:3000? ;)

Comment: Yes the correct action triggers

Comment: @DavidLosert the action triggers and everything on localhost:3000 works. Just localhost:3000/page/doSomething doesn’t work, says not found

Answer (score 0):

Ngrok can be used for different purposes like exposing your local web server, building webhooks, etc. If you wish to use it as a webhook, replace your base URL with the generated Ngrok URL of the webhook. and place it in the system needing a webhook to send back information to you. For any other purpose, you can make your question more specific.

PS. what I meant is put take `{{yuor_ngrok_url}}/page/doSomething` and place it in the portal that needs a webhook, get your local server running, and your Ngrok port forwarding it. then make a request to the remote server so that the response can come from the webhook.

Comment: Thank you, this totally worked for me. It’s funny though, had tried it earlier but it didn’t. Thanks once again

Comment: @Elvis, can you post the ngrok command you used to start your service? I am facing a similar issue but it does not work. I start ngrok with this command: "ngrok http localhost:57551". I have a local ASP.Net Web API running on port 57551. I submitted my webhook url as "https://{my_ngrok_url}/api/webhook". Accessing the local ngrok Web Interface on "http://127.0.0.1:4040" I see the received incoming HTTP POST call, but it is not forwarded to my local running Web API. Instead, I see an error saying "POST /api/webhook 400 Bad Request 0.51ms". I would really love to see how you solved this issue.

Comment: Further to my previous comment,  running "ngrok http localhost:57551/api/webhook", trying to explicitly indicate the URL where I want the webhook call redirected is not working as I am told that 'api/webhook' is not supported.